# Painting a Shape with a dynamic linear gradient brush

Tags: c#, wpf

I can find nothing to fix this problem, only solutions that don't work. I am trying to programmatically set the linear gradient brush on a cylinder in WPF. The sample code is my latest try to do this, the first bit the painting from the .xaml file and the second from the .xaml.cs file.

```
<Cyl:Cylinder Slices="128" TextureType="Drawing" 
                Point1="0 0 0" Point2="0 6 0" 
                Radius1="4" Radius2="4"
                Fold1="0.16" Fold2="0.84">
        <Cyl:Cylinder.Material>                        
             <DiffuseMaterial 
                    Brush="{Binding Path=Slide}">                           
             </DiffuseMaterial>
     </Cyl:Cylinder.Material>                    
</Cyl:Cylinder>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow(string[] color)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            setColors clsColor = new setColors();           
            LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(                   
                   Color.FromArgb(255,255, 0, 0),
                   Color.FromArgb(255,0, 255, 0),
                   new Point(0, 0.5),
                   new Point(1, 0.5));
            clsColor.Slide = linGrBrush;    
            this.DataContext = clsColor;            
        }

        public class setColors
        {            
            LinearGradientBrush LinGrBrush;            

            public LinearGradientBrush Slide
            {
                get
                { return LinGrBrush; }
                set { LinGrBrush = value; }
            }            
        }    
}
```

Using `Brush="{DynamicResource myBrush}"`, with accompanying line `this.Resources["myBrush"] = linGrBrush;` used instead of using DataContext also paints nothing. Is there any way I can get this working or ?

Answer (score 0):

For setting the colors/brushes on your xaml controls you should not use view model. Either it can be done in code-behind i.e. xaml.cs or if you wish to change the appearance on certain condition without using code-behind, it should be done through converters.

Moreover the property change gets reflected on UI in MVVM is by calling OnPropertyChangedMethod in each public property's setter. You get this method in the interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

Check more on this interface and am sure your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this example 
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/572bb28e-5a89-4117-8673-ea035e6ee1dd/how-to-access-local-variables-in-xaml-wpf) which I think is what you are talking about does not work.